# Game fla file missing from Starling build - possible recovery or decompile?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, decompiler, fla

I've been working with a programmer on an app and we've since gone our separate ways. I was passed on a copy of what was supposed to be the source code of everything at the end. However, I believe I'm missing a crucial file from the app build.

It's a pretty cool, but fairly basic 2D game. Built with Starling (gamua.com/starling) in ActionScript 3.

My question is, with all the files and assets mentioned below, is it possible to recover, reverse engineer, perhaps decompile, what I need to complete the app. Or will this project's code need to be re-written from scratch?

In my game 'build' I have following folders: 
assets, bin-debug, extensions, libs, src, and system.

I am a bit of a noob in coding (as you've probably gathered), but it looks like I'm missing the .fla file from the 'src' folder. The contents of that src folder is:
com, utils (folders), Constants.as, Game.as, Main-app.xml, Main.as, Menu.as, Root.as

I was hoping that there is enough information in the .as files intact, that the restoring of the .fla to compile the build is not a big ask?

If other questions stand out to you, please ask.
Thanks!

Comment: But what are you using to compile, Animate CC? Is that why you need an FLA? Otherwise if using some commandline compiler or whatever else then I would expect the `Main.as` to be one that's sent to compiler for output of SWF (does Main.as code seem to `import Constants;` and `import Game;` etc etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, Starling game is not built in the same way as a regular Flash game in the old days. You files look to me a lot like **FlashDevelop** project (there also should be **.as3proj** file somewhere in the root folder of the sources), which does not use FLA and compile the game from **.as** classes directly.

**P.S.** Or, maybe, **Flash/Flex Builder** project. Regardless, the possibility there were no FLAs to begin with is high.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that Organis. I was hoping to find someone familiar enough with AS3 and Starling that I could get a proper assessment of where my app is at. It sounds like I've made a few incorrect assumptions when trying to import the project myself. I guess I'm not surprised. Would I be able to speak with you about getting a copy of this project to you to take a look at for me?

Comment: @SmokinGun If there is *.as3proj file, then it is **FlashDevelop** projects and it is not that hard to make it work. If it is **Flash/Flex Builder**, I cannot help you much for it's been years since I used any of them. There also could be **build.xml**, which means project can be built with **Ant** + **Flex SDK**.